# AppBarLayout scrolling content below Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'd like to have a content area below my Toolbar. Its behavior should be to scroll while scrolling up and to enter immediately while scrolling down. Toolbar should stay on its place without any scrolling.

My layout is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/box_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_search_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Line 1"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_search_category"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_search_filter"
                android:text="Line 2"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_search_location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_search_category"
                android:text="Line 3"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If I put content area above Toolbar I am able to get the desired effect, but obviously it's in the wrong position.

If I put content area below Toolbar nothing scrolls...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I put content area above Toolbar I am able to get the desired
>   effect, but obviously it's in the wrong position.

Of course it is in the wrong position since: http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar

> The app bar, formerly known **as the action bar in Android**, **is a special
>   kind of toolbar** that’s used for branding, navigation, search, and
>   actions.

So, you need to add a [**`CollapsingToolbarLayout`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) and the contents on it.

And:

> I'd like to have a content area below my Toolbar. ***Its behavior should
>   be to scroll while scrolling up and to enter immediately while
>   scrolling down, Toolbar should stay on its place without any
>   scrolling.***

To not to scrolling the `Toolbar` after adding that `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, you may want to add `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` to that `Toolbar`.

Comment: Just tried. Everything collapses, including Toolbar (even with app:layout_collapseMode="pin")... :(

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using the wrong flag for that `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, Check this link : http://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout But all i'm saying is, this is the best way to do that!

Comment: Like i guessed, Check this: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#creating-collapsing-effects And try to use: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. of course it'll be collapsed with your codes..

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Since my original suggestion did not work, another method to achieve the desired outcome would be to break out the Toolbar from the CoordinatorLayout.  You can structure your layout XML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/box_search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_search_filter"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Line 1"
                    android:textColor="#FFF" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_search_category"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/text_search_filter"
                    android:text="Line 2"
                    android:textColor="#FFF" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_search_location"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/text_search_category"
                    android:text="Line 3"
                    android:textColor="#FFF" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <include layout="@layout/content_main"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If it's still not working, you should consider not using the include statement as this might be the source of the issues.  Rather, bring in the layout definition directly into this layout and place under a NestedScrollView (apply app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to this NestedScrollView).  If you need additional help, post the contents of your content_main layout XML in your OP.

**Original Response:**

Make sure you define the app:layout_behavior for your main content, which defines that the scrolling of the main content should affect the AppBarLayout.  Specifically, try this:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: Extracting Toolbar from AppBarLayout gives awful results, with the toolbar going under content...

Comment: Post the contents of your content_main layout.  Let's see what you've got